# How to filter the column of one DataFrame by the value of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my df1, that has 365 values for 365 days in a year

```
    Date  Data_Value
0  01-01        33.3
1  01-02        30.6
2  01-03        31.1
3  01-04        30.0
4  01-05        30.0
5  01-06        31.1
6  01-07        31.1
```

And here is my df2 which has 7262 rows of data containing several rows for one date of the year.

```
mnth_day  Data_Value
0    10-07        30.0
1    10-18        21.1
2    02-25        14.4
3    03-22        28.9
4    02-25        28.9
5    09-03        24.4
6    11-19        25.0
```

I need to check in how many days 'Data_Value' in df2 exceeds 'Data_Value' in df1. How can I do that?

---

My expected output will look like:

```
    Date  Data_Value
0  01-01        33.3
1  01-02        30.6
2  01-03        31.1
3  01-04        30.0
4  01-05        30.0
5  01-06        31.1
6  01-07        31.1
```

Here the 'Date' column will be in which date the 'Data_Value' in df2 exceeds the 'Data_Value' of df1. and 'Data_Value' column will be that biggest 'Data_Value'.

Comment: Please add your expected output to your question as well.

Comment: my expected output will look like:

Comment: Your expected output is exactly like your input. Could you please clarify, or use a more representative example?

Comment: let me guess, you want merge , then filter the value ?